# ¿Cómo podría hacer estas modificaciones en una sola expresión regular en php?

Tags: php, regex

me gustaría poder hacer las modificaciones en una sola expresión regular.
Lo que pretendo hacer es poder quitar los ceros al principio y eliminar los espacios, lo hice en dos expresiones regulares, pero me gustaría poder hacerlo en una sola.

```
$string = "000000  003  0003  000004334549 54600     960";

$conEx1 = preg_replace('/^0+/','',$string);
$conEx2 = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$conEx1);
echo  "\n$conEx2";
//menos lineas 
$conExArray = preg_replace(array('/\s+/','/^0+/'),'',$string);
echo  "\n$conExArray";

//intenté hacer pasándole un array pero busco poder hacerlo en una sola expresión
$conArray= preg_replace(array('/\s+/','/^0+/'),'',$string);

echo  "\n$conArray";
//intente hacer algo así, pero no me funciona

$conUna = preg_replace('/^0+.(\s+)/','',$string);
echo "\n$conUna";

?>
```

salida

```
003000300000433454954600960
003000300000433454954600960
003  0003  000004334549 54600     960
```

edito el orden es importante

```
$string = "000000  003  0003  000004334549 54600     960";
$conEx2 = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$string);
$conEx1 = preg_replace('/^0+/','',$conEx2);
```

salida

```
3000300000433454954600960
```

Comment: Prueba si esto te sirve `preg_replace('/^0+|\s+/','',$string);`

Answer (score 1):

Es complicado hacerlo con solo una expresión regular...

Podrías hacer uso de métodos externos para separar el string y luego usar esta expresión regular

```
/^[0]{1,}/m
```

Quedando así el ejemplo final

```
$str = '000000  003  0003  000004334549 54600     960';
$numbers = trim(join(" ", explode("\n", preg_replace("/^[0]{1,}/m", "", join("\n", array_filter(explode(" ", trim($str))))))));
print($numbers);
```

Primero vamos a separar el string por cada espacio con [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php), hasta ahí tendríamos algo así

```
[
    0 => 000000
    1 => 
    2 => 
    3 => 003 
    4 => 
    5 => 0003
    6 => 
    7 => 
    8 => 000004334549
    9 => 54600 
    10 => 
    11 => 
    12 => 
    13 => 960
)
```

Porque tenemos espacios en blanco, por ende vamos a usar [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php), se especifica que si la función *callback* no es especificada (como en este caso) quita todos los elementos vacíos del array, entonces tendríamos un array más corto, algo así

```
[
    0 => 000000
    1 => 003
    2 => 0003
    3 => 000004334549
    4 => 54600
    5 => 960
)
```

Luego de eso, vamos a usar [`join()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.join) (Alias de [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php)) para unir el array y obtener un string que tenga una línea por cada elemento del array, el string sería algo así

```
000000
003
0003
000004334549
54600
960
```

Y volvemos a la expresión del inicio con [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace), vamos a reemplazar todos los ceros usando esta expresión

```
/^[0]{1,}/m
```

Con el flag *multiline* para que haga *match* a todas las líneas por separado y no tome a todo el string como una sola línea, el método nos dará un array el cual vamos a unir con `join()`, pero esta vez uniremos cada elemento con un espacio, finalmente usamos [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.trim) para quitar los espacios iniciales y finales innecesarios

**Quedando la salida así**

```
3 3 4334549 54600 960
```

[DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/rkvJ21_EO)

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría con la función [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php), claro, siguiendo tu ejemplo de que das los números como una cadena de texto, simplemente usas esa función para buscar cada espacio en blanco dentro de tu string y reemplazarlos por lo que quieras, en este caso, no tener espacio. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
//Tu string a reemplazar
$string = "000000  003  0003  000004334549 54600     960";

//Reemplazamos los espacios en blanco y los 0. 
//Se le puede pasar un array como argumento caracteres a buscar.
$salida = str_replace([' ', '0'], '', $string);

//Se obtiene como salida el siguiente string: string(14) "33433454954696"
var_dump($salida);
```

Espero te sea de utilidad y sea lo que buscas. Saludos.

**[AQUÍ ESTÁ EL DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9529da7ace55a06d6f465a2ebc9c41c79f2da6c)**

Comment: sí, es que lo recibo como cadena de texto, luego hago un intval para trabajar con él

Comment: Bueno, creo que más que usar un regex para hacer eso, pues te va a ser más útil usar la función str_replace.